How to make a template for part of a cabinet door
I have a cabinet door I'm sanding with my kids. My older one got too aggressive and damaged the wood so I bought a veneer that I wanted to stick to the middle of the door. There's like this frame section and a recessed area inside and this recessed area is where the damage is. Problem is that the recessed area isn't a perfect rectangle. There's a curvy section like the Bell curve. I've tried creating a template out of tape where I stick a bunch of tape to the door and then transfer the tape to the wood veneer, however it doesn't come out right when I cut the new section out with a knife.
Anyone got some tips on how to do this right?

Some photos would sure help your cause...

Paper and charcoal or graphite or crayon - essentially the same technique as making a rubbing of a gravestone, only you're looking for the edges of the recessed area, not cut lettering.
Scribble back and forth across the edge, and the edge will make a change in how the pigment takes to the paper, which you can follow with scissors to cut the pattern.
Unlike tape, you can remove the paper without stretching and distorting it. A few bits of tape will serve to hold it in position.
